# cannot import name '_request_ctx_stack' from 'flask' while starting flask-login

Tags: flask, flask-login, werkzeug

I have commented out all references to flask-login in my application and the application works.
Typing the command:
`from flask_login import LoginManager`
generates errors already at the startup stage: flask shell .
The last error is:
`ImportError: cannot import name '_request_ctx_stack' from 'flask' (/. . . /iws/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/__init__.py)`

I have all the packages necessary for the Flask framework installed.
I am working on Ubuntu 22.04/Debian 12., Python3.10 and Flask3.0.0, flask-login0.6.2/0.6.1, Werkzeug3.0.0
Someone may have an idea what the problem is?
I swapped versions of the Flask-login package and the Werkzeug wedding, changed the operating system and Python version to version 3.9.
Eventually I discovered that I get the same errors trying to run Flask Shell.
I also tried to use the instructions in the blog
[text](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins/page/24#comments)

Answer (score 0):

you need latest flask-login sources (that will probably be v0.7.0 in next release), 0.6.2 version is not compatible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).